# Would be a good option to create classes as extensions?

Tags: c#, random, abstract-class, wrapper

This is the code which I'm using a wrapper extension for a random class.

```
public static class RandomHelper
{
    private static int currentSeed;
    private static Random rd = new Random();

    public static double Next()
    {
        return rd.NextDouble();
    }

    public static double Next(double min, double max)
    {
        return (rd.NextDouble() * (max - min)) + min;
    }

    public static double NextOnStep(double min, double max, double step)
    {
        int range = (int)Math.Floor((max - min) / step);
        int stepCount = rd.Next(0, range);
        return min + (step * stepCount);
    }

    public static double NextOnDecimalCount(double min, double max, int decimals)
    {
        double step = Math.Pow(10, decimals);
        return Math.Truncate(((rd.NextDouble() * (max - min)) + min) * step) / step;
    }
```

And imagine this situation, I have a class where contains three ranges of numbers

```
public class ArithmeticProblemGenerator()
{
    Range Number1Range {get;set;}
    Range Number2Range {get;set;}
    ...
    Range Number5Range {get;set;}
}

public class Range
{
    public Range()
    {
    }

    public Range(double min, double max)
    {
        this.Min = min;
        this.Max = max;
    }

    public double Min { get; set; }
    public double Max { get; set; }
}
```

And when I want to generate the problem, I add another method in my RandomHelper as extesion.

```
    #region RandomHelper extensions

    public static double Next(Range range)
    {
        return Next(range.Min, range.Max);
    }

    public static double NextOnStep(Range range, double step)
    {
        return NextOnStep(range.Min, range.Max, step);
    }

    public static double NextOnDecimalCount(Range range, int decimals)
    {
        return NextOnDecimalCount(range.Min, range.Max, decimals);
    }

    #endregion
```

But then I add a new feature of my ArithmeticProblemGenerator,  I want to have numbers with different decimal places or sometimes the number follow a step.

So, I supposed, will it be good to create another two classes to add the following features.

```
public class RangeOnStep : Range
{
    public RangeOnStep()
    {
    }

    public RangeOnStep(double min, double max, double step)
        : base(min, max)
    {
        this.Step = step;
    }

    public double Step { get; set; }
}

public class RangeOnDecimalPlace : Range
{
    public RangeOnDecimalPlace()
    {
    }

    public RangeOnDecimalPlace(double min, double max, double decimalPlaces)
        : base(min, max)
    {
        this.DecimalPlaces = decimalPlaces;
    }

    public double DecimalPlaces { get; set; }
}
```

And add another method extensions with these new classes. Do you think I'm doing a good work or is a mess the design?

I wanna hear suggestions or opinions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

method extension isn't usefull here, why not use a base class range and define overriden method like:

public static class RandomHelper 
{ 
    private static int currentSeed; 
    private static Random rd = new Random();

```
public static double Next() 
{ 
    return rd.NextDouble(); 
} 

public static double Next(double min, double max) 
{ 
    return (rd.NextDouble() * (max - min)) + min; 
} 

public static double Next(RangeOnStep r) 
{ 
    int range = (int)Math.Floor((r.max - r.min) / r.step); 
    int stepCount = rd.Next(0, range); 
    return r.min + (step * stepCount); 
} 

public static double Next(RangeOnDecimalPlace r)) 
{ 
    double step = Math.Pow(10, r.decimals); 
    return Math.Truncate(((rd.NextDouble() * (r.max - r.min)) + r.min) * step) / step; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem I have found when using static helper classes (whether extension methods or not) is that they are difficult to mock when it comes to unit testing code which is dependent on these statics. This will be true for your case too, since you undoubtedly want to test cases where your random number generator returns values in specific ranges.

I've typically tried to replace the static helpers with instance classes with interfaces, and then use an IoC to inject a singleton of the 'helper' into my dependent classes (i.e. coupled on  interfaces only) - this way the helpers can be mocked and your class fully tested.

Comment: I've understand your last paragraph and thanks for the point. I've never done a unit test, and I don't know why static classes are difficult to test. Can you tell me a bit more for that situation and the mocks?

Comment: @darf zon - this should give you an idea of the challenges - http://www.google.com/webhp?q=unit+testing+static+classes